# Can I force chrome or another browser to use an older version of javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm using pdfkit (https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) to produce a pdf document from html.  The html contains charts built with plotly; the plotly is driven by some javascript code from a script tag in the html.

Because pdfkit supports only an older version of javascript, I need to avoid certain newer javascript features (like `let` instead of `var`, and arrow functions).  When I view the generated html in chrome, even if I've used newer javascript features, it looks fine, because chrome supports modern javascript.  So I only see problems in the derived pdf document, and that makes finding the errors difficult.  What I'd like to be able to do is to tell the browser to use an older version of javascript so I can see my errors in a more useful context.

Is there a way to tell chrome or some other browser to use an older version of javascript?

Comment: Browsers will automatically support javascript that isn't es6 (such as let, arrow functions, etc.), it is that not all browsers support the es6 features. So I am a little confused by your question, perhaps you can explain the problem you are having outside of the solution you want. Sounds like an XY problem - http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @kyle I want my errors, specifically my use of too-modern javascript features, to be apparent in the browser, before generating pdf.  The problem I'm having is that I can't see my errors in a useful context; the browser is a useful context and the pdf isn't.

Comment: You can just download an older version of the browser for this particular test. I had a similar issue and just downloaded Chrome 20 (which is the last version with no ECMA2015 support). If your application runs in IE then that is also a good test bed as just set it to IE10 or IE9 and you have no ECMA2015 support). I tried loads of extensions but they were all basically linters so they don't help with live testing.

Comment: @CarlManaster I understand your question now. You could consider using browser stack for testing the functionality in other browser. I would also consider transpiling your code with babel or something. You can tell babel what browser and versions you want to support and it will polyfill missing features along with fixing the arrow functions.

Comment: if I got what your issue right, then I suggest that you use a linter for your code instead of using older version of a browser/javascript, for javascript you can use [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) to make sure that your code doesn't have ES6+ features, and also you can have it integrated into your build tool.

Comment: @CarlManaster There are multiple packages called "pdfkit". I've found one for Node, and one for Python. They are very different from one another. Please edit your question to provide a link to the specific package you are using. This will help people help you.

Comment: Thanks @Louis; I've edited my question to specify the python pdfkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow this https://babeljs.io/setup#installation to install babel or add babel cdn, then you need to install es2015 preset with `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-es2015`. Create .babelrc file and add following:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-es2015"]
}
```

for more information how it works visit https://babeljs.io/repl